# JOptionPane.showInputDialog is displayed twice, why?

Tags: java, swing

I'm recently developing an swing app in java and the issue is that every time i need to input data into JOptionPane.showInputDialog this is called twice and no matter what i do in a basic test always is showed double. In the first window i enter data and when clicked accept another window is also displayed simultaneously, ignoring the first one. It's important to mention my app is running right but when i need to execute the switch sentence in the choice No. 3 it's when the problem occurs.

here my code.

```
private void jcTemplatesItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                             

    int seleccionar = jcTemplates.getSelectedIndex();

    switch (seleccionar) {

        case 1:

            templateField2.setText(jcTipoCliente.getSelectedItem() + " " + txtCliente.getText() + " comenta que no reconoce POD. Favor de realizar rescate del envio y entregarlo en la direccion correcta. Se le informa sobre proceso y tiempo requerido de 24-48 hrs. Queda Ok. Gracias.  ");
            break;

        case 2:
            templateField2.setText(jcTipoCliente.getSelectedItem() + " " + txtCliente.getText() + " llama para requerir informacion sobre el status del envio, ya que menciona que ha tomado demasiado tiempo y requiere confirmar fecha de entrega. Favor de actualizar a la brevedad. Se le pide tiempo y queda Ok. Gracias. ");
            break;

        case 3:

            String dato = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "NCI", "Verificar", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == 0) 
                templateField2.setText(dato);
             else if (JOptionPane.NO_OPTION == 1) 
                dispose();
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An `ItemListener` may fire two events. One for `itemDeselected` and one for `itemSelected`. You only want to dislay the option pane for the selected event.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ItemListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for more information and a working example to get you started.